# Extract all code committed by a certian author in Git

Tags: git, version-control

How to extract all the code committed by a certain author to a text file in Git?

If there is a repository and I want to have all code of a certain committer over the history of the repo from its start from its master branch in one text file.

Try to use `git log --author="Jon"` and it will show the commit message and the date of all the commits of him but without the code itself, I need this information along with the code to be outputted in one text file. I hope this made what I want clear.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.  What do you mean by "extract all code"?  Also, do you mean over the entire history of the project, the latest version of a file, or something else?

Comment: Is a diff fine?  You could use `-p` to the log command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git log -p --author="John"`, and that will give you the *path* representing what code has been modified.

For getting all the patches in one file, see "[`git diff` with author filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3512492/6309)".