# How to run git diff with having revision info in the resulting output

Tags: git, blame, git-blame

I need to get `git diff` output which is expected to have revision info to each line i.e.

```
$ git diff f08cbec42b80725e7840ae3d05f790f6fa9daa8e..cbe1c77ad85c58be93964bd8b8fb624f654b7670
```

```
    diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
    index a54324ff7a..164c5fcfab 100644
    --- a/.gitignore
    +++ b/.gitignore
    @@ -9,6 +9,7 @@
                   */target
                   /build
                   */build
    Vasya.Pupkin: +testdb
```

Actually I need just Author's name

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509419/git-diff-with-author-filter

Answer (score 0):

You need `git log -p` or `git annotate` or `git blame`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need neither `git blame` nor `git log -p`. 
I need to have a `git diff` with revision info for corresponding lines